How to pass a file pointer by reference for writing in a flex lexer?
I need help with a flex program. The program must analyze a string entered by the user and define if they are constants, identifiers, numerals or if there are no errors, these results need to be stored by the program in a scan.txt file. The problem is that I am not able to pass the file pointer by reference to yywrap.  Using ChatGPT it gave me functions like yyset_extras and yyscan_t, but I did not find any information about these functions so I suspect that it must be an AI allusion.
%option reentrant
/* Declaraciones */
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define YY_EXTRA_TYPE FILE*
%}

/* Reglas */
%%
  /* Constantes Enteras */
[0-9]+  {fprintf(yyextra,"Constante Entera\n");}
      
  /* Identificadores */
([a-zA-Z])([0-9]|[a-zA-Z])+ {fprintf(yyextra,"Identificador\n");}

  /* Numeral */
[#] {fprintf(yyextra,"Numeral\n");}

  /* Default */
.   {fprintf(yyextra,"Error\n");}

\n {return 0;}
%%

/* Auxiliar */
int yywrap() {
    return 1;
}
int main(){
    FILE *scan = fopen("scan.txt","w");
    if (scan == NULL) {
        perror("Error al abrir el archivo de salida");
        return 1;
    }
    yyscan_t scanner;
    yylex_init(&scanner);
    // Configurar yyextra para que apunte al archivo de salida
    yyset_extra(scan, scanner);
    yylex(scanner);
    yylex_destroy(scanner);
    fclose(scan);
    return 0;
}

If anyone knows how I can pass the file pointer so that as it analyzes the string entered by the user, it saves the results in the .txt, it would be of great help to me. I am attaching my code below.

You've handled the output side of things fine -- you pass a FILE * as yyextra in the scanner and use it to output what you want.
For input, however, the scanner just reads from stdin (the default).  You need to call
yy_scan_string(input_string, scanner);

before calling yylex (and after yylex_init) to take the input from input_string, which is just a char * (a string) containing the string to be scanned.  You'll need to implement code to "get the user to enter a string", but there are many ways of doing that, and it is pretty much independent of flex.

Alternately, you could use yyout instead of yyextra as that is always a FILE *.  Use yyset_out(scan, scanner); in main, and change your output functions to fprintf(yyout.  This would also get anything that doesn't match any rule copied to it, but as your rules cover all possible inputs (between the . rule and the \n rule), it doesn't matter.

Of course I understand that, not to use yy_scan_string(input_string, scanner);
It makes use of the default console entry, which is not really the problem I have. The problem really is that I don't understand how to use the .txt file pointer within the rules part. Currently I get an error that talks about yywrap() and its number of arguments.
Error:
scannerfile.txt: In function 'yywrap':
scannerfile.txt:29:8: error: number of arguments doesn't match prototype
29 |         return 1;
| ^       ~~
lex.yy.c:526:12: error: prototype declaration
526 | #else

For a reentrant scanner (like you have), you need to declare it as int yywrap(yyscan_t) { return 1; }.  Alternately, use %option noyywrap and get rid of it.
